# CSS: white space outside html page

Tags: html, css

I've a page and in a particular section I'm seeing and extrange white space beneth the footer.

I was wondering what could be possible be happeing as it only happens in this seccion of the website:

https://stickersgallito.pe/carrito_de_compras/

[image]

**Selected it says it is outside the HTML tags:**

[image]

Comment: Because that is the height of the page and its content. To see it, open your inspect tool and set the `.container` class to 1000px's. You'll notice no white space at the bottom of the page. You can also see this with your `#footer-navbar`. You are setting its `margin-top: 534.328px`.

Comment: you can arrange it  divide  section by section for your control in a particular area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's happening because the content of the page is not enough to fill the viewport/screen-size.
So If you add a few more contents to this page, it will solve your problem.**

If you don't have more content & want to show footer at the bottom of the page, here is the solution:

```
#footer-navbar {
    background-color: rgb(239, 239, 239);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**Use this CSS only on this page.**
Thanks

Comment: how to apply only to a page? If I put this directly in the html will work (inside style tags)?

Comment: Yes, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your `footer-navbar` selector. You have an odd margin applied to it that is forcing that section rather than letting it flow properly.